# Using azure blob storage as repository for gradle

Tags: gradle, azure-devops

I am trying to set up an artifact repository on Azure Blob Storage. I will like to publish my artifact, generated through gradle build, to this repo and later use this artifact as dependency in some other gradle project.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Azure File Copy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-file-copy?view=azure-devops) to copy your artifatc to Microsoft Azure storage blobs. Then, you can [Download blobs from Azure Blob Storage by using AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs-download) as dependency.

Answer (score 0):

This response may be delayed, but I encountered a similar issue and was able to resolve it by using SFTP to publish the artifact to a blob container. To do this, you will need to follow these steps:

In your build.gradle file, set up the Maven publish plugin to declare the Maven repository that you want to publish to using SFTP.
Provide your SFTP credentials to authenticate and authorize the publish action.
By following these steps, you should be able to publish your artifact to the blob container successfully.

```
publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId '<com. ... group here>'
            artifactId '<artifactId here>'
            version '1.0.0.0'
            artifact 'build/outputs/aar/...-release.aar'
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'sftp://<workspace name here>.blob.core.windows.net:22'
            credentials {
                username "<username here>"
                password "<password here>"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To read the published artifact you declare in settings.gradle

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        // Using Blob Storage
        maven {
            url 'sftp://<workspace name here>.blob.core.windows.net:22'
            credentials {
                username "<username here>"
                password "<password here>"
            }
        }
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
    }
}
```

and in your dependecies you can now use your artifact

```
dependencies {
    // Add Dependency
    implementation(group: '<com. ... group here>', name: '<artifactId here>', version: '1.0.0.0')
    // Other dependencies goes here
}
```

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could adapt this Maven-based approach to use Gradle.

https://tech.asimio.net/2020/09/01/Using-Azure-Blob-Storage-as-your-Maven-Repository.html

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the blog post.